# What is SCHEMABINDING? And for what purpose we use it?

Tags: sql-server

What is SCHEMABINDING? And for what purpose we use it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and then visit [ask] to understand how this question can be improved.

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` because the term schemabinding does not exist in the query language SQL

Answer (score 4):

Using `WITH SCHEMABINDING` indicates that the underlying table the view is referencing cannot have its schema changed. They are 'bound' together in essence.

The reason this is important is because SQL Server does not need to check periodically to see whether or not the schema has changed.  This speeds up the performance of views, and is required for  Indexed Views.

[ask.sqlservercentral.com has more detail](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/2582/what-is-schemabinding.html).

Answer (score 1):

SCHEMABINDING can be used with view to bind base table definition means you can not change structure of base table which affects view definition. first you need to modify or drop the view structure in case of data binding to remove dependencies. Here modification of base table means dropping table, adding column or removing column etc.

Answer (score 1):

SCHEMABINDING is a special option which deprecates alteration in such objects which are referred by the schema bound object. For example Views can be schema bound which means that all the object(like tables) which are referenced by that view can't be changed or modified (like you can't drop a referenced column from them, but adding a new column is allowed though not recommended). Sometimes, f. ex. while creating indexes on views, SHEMABOUND option is mandatory