# Create enforce on SQL Server Tables which is used in regular SQL View

Tags: sql-server

I have created a SQL View by joining multiple tables and view is consumed by numerous real-time dashboards.

I want to ensure that no changes to the underlying schema impacts the SQL View. How can we enforce this?

Comment: By adding `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to the definition. [Benefits of SCHEMABINDING in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4673/benefits-of-schemabinding-in-sql-server/) explains this. The [CREATE VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) docs also explain how this works but there's no direct link to the `SCHEMABINDING` section

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is SCHEMABINDING? And for what purpose we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961779/what-is-schemabinding-and-for-what-purpose-we-use-it)